# Configure Aptana to not include svn folder in FTP transfer

Tags: svn, ftp, aptana, fdt

Is it possible to configure the Aptana Remote Systems (FTP) transfer to not include svn hidden folders for uploads?

It shouldn't make any difference, but I'm running FDT 4 Plus rather than a basic Eclipse install, on Windows.  svn folders should not be deleted from the local workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm not sure if this will work, but it's worth to check out;*

> Click "**Window**" in the menubar and open "**Preferences**".
>
> Under "**Aptana**", click "**Remote**".

There you should be able to add file-extensions and names to be ignored in file transfers.

Comment: Oh, well now I feel stupid. `.svn` is already there. Thanks for pointing me to the right place, now it's clearly time for me to get some sleep!